# Spatial Join dilemma

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-join

I have multiple layers with 'many features' within. One layer is a larger boundary layer which contains these 'many features'. The example below shows my situation. The red outline polygon is the boundary layer and the various coloured layers within are the 'many features' which have an all important AREA (m2) field in each. For line features, this is LENGTH (m).
[image]
Ideally I want to spatially join all the 'many features' to each Boundary layer using 'HAVE_THEIR_CENTER_IN'.
However, this spatial join method looks at the centre of the Boundary polygon, not the centers of the multiple features. ie. It will join to the boudary layer, any layer which sits within the center of the boundary layer...
I want it to join any feature that has their center within the boundary layer, TO the boundary layer.

how should I best work around this problem?
It is the wrong way round for my task.

Answer (score 1):

You could create the centroid of each of your "multiple features" layer, then you join the boundary layer on the multiple features, then you use the attribute values to create on relation between the features of the boundary layer and the multiple features.